# How to get the current source directory in gradle?

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

I have different flavors in a gradle build file:

I would like to put a .properties file in each app/src/flavor/ directory

```
 app
   src
      flavor1/
         java/
         app.properties
      flavor2/
         java/
         app.properties
```

and then use the references to that file in a task.

How do I reference the current flavor's directory in groovy/gradle?

Comment: There is no concept of a "current flavor". What you are creating in `build.gradle` is an object model representing tasks. Only *after* the object model is created are tasks considered, and only *then* is there a concept of a "current flavor". But by then your `build.gradle` code has long since been run. The exception would be any custom tasks you create, and those usually are created for every flavor (e.g., by iterating over the variants).

Comment: what concept should I be looking into, to figure out how to reference app.properties file globally in the gradle script?

Comment: Off the cuff, I have no idea how I would do per-flavor properties files. What are you trying to accomplish with per-flavor properties files?

Comment: I have build.config values in them. I use flavors to represent different apps, so I use that file to put configurable data in each app.

Comment: "I have build.config values in them" -- I do not know what that means. If you mean `BuildConfig`, those should be defined in your `build.gradle` file. I fail too see what the advantage would be of having flavor-specific code in `build.gradle`, turning around and having to read in a flavor-specific properties file. That being said, you are welcome to have per-flavor properties files, but I would put them in the module root (e.g., `${flavor}.properties`) rather than try to put them in the sourceset.

Comment: that sounds exactly like what I need. "${flavor}.properties" -- is that how I would reference the file in build.gradle? def appProps = file({$flavor}.properties) Properties app = new Properties() try { app.load(appProps.newDataInputStream()) } ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want per-flavor properties, here's an off-the-cuff approach.

Step #1: Come up with your list of flavors. For the purposes of this answer, I'll use `vanilla` and `chocolate`.

Step #2: Create, in your module root, a properties file per flavor (i.e., `vanilla.properties`, `chocolate.properties`).

Step #3: In your `productFlavors` closure, you would have the code to load up that flavor's properties and use them, using something like this:

```
productFlavors {
    vanilla {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.android.gradle.hello.vanilla"

        def propFile = rootProject.file('vanilla.properties')

        if (propFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties flavorProps = new Properties()

            flavorProps.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

            // you can now access flavorProps[...] for various string keys
            // identified here as ..., like flavorProps['foo']
        }
    }

    // repeat for chocolate and other flavors
}
```

The only wrinkle in the above code that I can think of off the top of my head is my use of `rootProject`. My sample code for all of these Gradle tricks are for a project without modules, but Android Studio projects often will be set up with your code in an `app/` module (a.k.a., subproject). I have not experimented with this code yet in that scenario, and I do not know if `rootProject` will refer to the module or the top-level project directory. There may be a different value to use, other than `rootProject`, to get to the module.

Comment: ill test it out and see...I was kinda already moving in this direction, setting everything up under the productFlavors closure. This will bring me closer indeed. ty